# Ubuntu Router - 2 NICs - cannot ping Internet from internal network

Tags: server, iptables, dhcp, interface, router

I have read many posts on how to configure 2 NICs, but some help would be very appreciated. I am planning to make a router using an Orange Pi R1. I have installed Ubuntu Xenial Server using an image from Armbian.

I have configured my interfaces like this:

```
# Wired adapter #1 (external interface)
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

#2nd eth interface (internal interface)
auto enxc0742bfff8b3
iface enxc0742bfff8b3 inet static
        address 192.168.2.1
        network 192.168.2.0
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 192.168.2.255

# Local loopback
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

On /etc/sysctl.conf, I enabled IP forwarding:

```
# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv4
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

The output of route -n is:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enxc0742bfff8b3
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enxc0742bfff8b3
```

I am running isc-dhcp-server on interface enxc0742bfff8b3. This is my /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server:

```
INTERFACES=enxc0742bfff8b3
```

and this is my /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf:

```
ddns-update-style none;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
subnet 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        range 192.168.2.100 192.168.2.200;
        }
```

My firewall is completely open with masquerading enabled:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Sun Apr  1 20:22:26 2018
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [544:42034]
:INPUT ACCEPT [544:42034]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [307:32628]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [307:32628]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Apr  1 20:22:26 2018
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Sun Apr  1 20:22:26 2018
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [2:346]
:INPUT ACCEPT [2:346]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1:128]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Apr  1 20:22:26 2018
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Sun Apr  1 20:22:26 2018
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [537:41562]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [303:31732]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Apr  1 20:22:26 2018
```

My eth0 gets 192.168.0.16 from my modem. I connected a laptop to enxc0742bfff8b3, and it received 192.168.2.100.

My external interface can ping internet:

```
root@orangepi:~# ping -I eth0 www.google.com
PING www.google.com (172.217.19.68) from 192.168.0.16 eth0: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ham02s17-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.19.68): icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=38.4 ms
64 bytes from ham02s17-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.19.68): icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=37.9 ms
64 bytes from ham02s17-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.19.68): icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=37.9 ms
```

And I can connect to it from any device on 192.168.0.X network.

But no device connected to the internal interface (192.168.2.X) can reach internet:

```
root@orangepi:~# ping -I enxc0742bfff8b3 192.168.0.16
PING 192.168.0.16 (192.168.0.16) from 192.168.2.1 enxc0742bfff8b3: 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.2.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.2.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.2.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable

root@orangepi:~# ping -I enxc0742bfff8b3 192.168.0.1
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) from 192.168.2.1 enxc0742bfff8b3: 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.2.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.2.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.2.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable

root@orangepi:~# ping -I enxc0742bfff8b3 www.google.com
PING www.google.com (172.217.19.68) from 192.168.2.1 enxc0742bfff8b3: 56(84) bytes of data.
From orangepi (192.168.2.1) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From orangepi (192.168.2.1) icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From orangepi (192.168.2.1) icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Could someone help me to understand what is missing?

Thanks,

RG